# pan google map to ISO 3166 country code on android

Tags: android, google-maps, iso

I have an android application that allows the user to select a default country.
Countries are held as ISO 3166 codes
Is there a way to automatically pan a Google v2 map to the chosen country using its iso3166 code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically

Nothing is done automatically. We do everything manually so it seems automatic. ;)

> pan a Google v2 map

```
theMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(...));
```

> to the chosen country using its iso3166 code?

Parse the output of

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=GB&sensor=false

to get the bounds.